# Servlets with different ports

Tags: java, servlets

I was reading the headfirst book about JSP and Servlets and I found out that different servlets have different ports and you should always ask which port is available when developing your own servlet.

Now this might have a very simple answer but I ran my servlet from this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/ch1/Serv1
```

Does that mean that my servlet has the port 8080? Can you please point me to a link which will explain these things in better detail?

All I get from Google searches is exactly what says in the book ( which I'm sure is right ) that all servlets have different ports.

Thank you

Comment: Your servlet doesn't have the port 8080. The underlying java application (in which your Servlet container is running) is listening on that port. Also, don't ask for 3rd party resources, that is off-topic.

Comment: No. That means your web server has the port 8080, Servlet(s) run in a web container (a special Java Servlet enabled web server). The only way your Servlet(s) would have different port numbers is if they were running in separate container(s). It's possible there may be a justification for that, but your understanding is/was flawed.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch and Sotirios Delimanolis Thank you so much. Tomcat would be my container in this case and has a socket open to listen to port 8080 right?

Comment: That is 100% correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Servlets are not bound to a port. The server (tomcat or jetty or whatever) is bound to a port.

Your Servlet is bound to a path.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Apache Tomcat: It provides more than one so called **Connector** which are used to interact with clients or other software components. One of its connectors is **HTTP**. In the `server.xml` configuration file you can freely configure the port the HTTP connector of your Servlet container will listen on. For example, you can make the HTTP connector listen on the default HTTP port 80.

Have a look here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Very true. Not to mention https!

Comment: Right. And if I would want to this manually without using Tomcat I would have to write a file which listens to a specific port manually. That's what headfirst was telling me. Thanks for clarifying it

Answer (score 0):

If you use `IntelliJ IDEA`, follow the steps below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And finally click **Apply** button